# How to pivot a table of unique strings by Type column (stagger strings by Type)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table that has Date, Type, and Item columns. Each string in the Item column is unique. I need to pivot this table so that each Item is sorted into a respective Type column.

[An illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Jry.png)

I googled both Pivot Table function, and QUERY formula, both do not work with strings reliably. But maybe I simply cannot see a proper way.

| Date | Type | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Jan 2020 | writing | pencil |
| 1 Jan 2020 | tool | hammer |
| 2 Jan 2020 | clothes | shoes |
| 2 Jan 2020 | writing | pen |
| 3 Jan 2020 | clothes | shirt |
| 3 Jan 2020 | clothes | trousers |

I want to turn it into this:

| - | Clothes | Tool | Writing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Jan 2020 |  | hammer |  |
| 1 Jan 2020 |  |  | pencil |
| 2 Jan 2020 | shoes |  |  |
| 2 Jan 2020 |  |  | pen |
| 3 Jan 2020 | shirt |  |  |
| 3 Jan 2020 | trousers |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using QUERY:

```
=arrayformula(query({row(A:A),A:C},"select Col2,max(Col4) where Col2 is not null group by Col1,Col2 pivot Col3",1))
```

*Pivot*/*group by* in `query` always requires some form of aggregation to work; you can use *min* or *max* with strings and a column of unique values (derived in this instance from the `row` function as your data does not contain a uniquely-valued column) to obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Λ;torow(sort(unique(tocol(B2:B;1))));
    vstack(hstack(;Λ);map(A2:A;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;hstack(Σ;let(Ξ;chooserows(filter(B:C;A:A=Σ);countif(A2:Σ;Σ));index(if(Λ=index(Ξ;;1);index(Ξ;;2);)))))))))
```

[image]